# Min(date) in BigQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I've recently switched from Workbench to BigQuery and I've noticed some differences in syntax when building queries. BigQuery struggles with a very basic SQL query:

```
SELECT createdAt, incrementId, customerEmail  
FROM order
WHERE customerEmail = 'email'
```

Here's the output:

[image]

When I wanna return the first row with earliest date:

```
SELECT MIN(createdAt), incrementId, customerEmail 
FROM order
WHERE customerEmail = 'email'
GROUP BY incrementId, cutomerEmail
```

This query returns the exact same table. Any idea what might be wrong here? Column 'createdAt' is a timestamp in the table schema.

Comment: *When I wanna return the first row with earliest date* then you must order by this date and select only 1st row (LIMIT 1). *This query returns the exact same table.* Of course, the values pair of the grouping expression have no duplicates, so each row is separate group.

Answer (score 1):

When you group by `incrementId, customerEmail` and the values do not have duplicates all the distinct values will be returned. You can get the `MIN(createdAt)` from subquery.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT createdAt, 
       incrementId, 
       customerEmail 
FROM order
WHERE customerEmail = 'email'
AND createdAt= (select MIN(createdAt) FROM order) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this almost worked, it turned out the proper syntax is:

```
SELECT createdAt, 
       incrementId, 
       customerEmail 
FROM order
WHERE customerEmail = 'email'
AND createdAt= (select MIN(createdAt) FROM order
WHERE customerEmail = 'email');
```